# Wordpress / PHP - Edit filename on load to bust cache

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

As it is now I'm using query strings to bust browser cache when updating css and js. However, as noted many places, not all browsers always respects/checks for new query strings. For instance I experienced this with Internet Explorer 11 which didn't load a new js file, even though a new version with a new query string was available (and loaded in chrome).

Therefore I would like to change the actual filename of the files, to completely avoid this issue.

I would like the structure of the filename to change from e.g. `my-custom.js` to `my-custom-1231141.js` where the numbers are fetched from `filemtime`.

I've tried using the PHP `rename()` function merged with wordpress `wp_register_script`, but this didn't work, and something tells me that it's wrong use of `rename()`.

Is this possible - and will it make any sense to do so with regards to server usage?

In essence what I would like to happen is the following:

1. Visitor HTTP requests
2. Fetch `my-custom.js`
3. Rename/rewrite `my-custom.js` to `my-custom-1231141.js` based the file's `filemtime` while preserving contents
4. Serve `my-custom-1231141.js` to the visitor

Answer (score 0):

You may use revision version in filename w-out rename of file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js?<?php echo $some_string;?>"></script>
```

of if you not want to use cached version

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js?<?php echo mt_rand(1, 9999);?>"></script>
```

Comment: The question is about finding an alternative to your answer which he claims does not always work. Quote:"with Internet Explorer 11 which didn't load a new js file, even though a new version with a new query string was available "